# GEF: How to draw diagram bottom up

Tags: layout, position, eclipse-gef, draw2d, bottom-up

I'm trying to draw a tree within a GEF editor. The problem is that I need to draw it bottom up. I have a primary layer for the node figures, and a connection layer for the connections.
The primary layer is a `FreeformLayer`, the root edit part a `ScalableFreeformLayeredPane`. The primary layer has a `XYLayout`.

Now I need to find the bottom edge of the editor (= viewport???) in order to be able to draw the bottom level of figures ("tokens") at that position (bottom y of primary layer - height of tokens = y of tokens). How can I get that?

I've tried to do it with `BorderLayout` so the tokens get painted at the bottom of the editor (`BorderLayout.BOTTOM`), and the nodes above it in `BorderLayout.CENTER`, but I've run into trouble with selections, and the layout is far from what I want to achieve.

So basically I want to have all nodes in one layer. I can set the position of the tokens, but the nodes above them must be calculated dynamically. How can I do this within `XYLayout`?

Many thanks in advance!

(Alternatively, positioning the tokens in the y-centered would be acceptable if it's easier to achieve)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Zest Layout Algorithms to have some inspiration:
http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/

Comment: Thanks, will do that, although I think Zest works quite differently?

Comment: Zest is a visualization framework based on gef and has some articulated layout algorithms. perhaps you can base your solution on one of these :)

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that I need all the editing capabilities that GEF (the plug-in, not the framework) offers. Would it be possible to use Zest to layout figures in a GEF editor?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884792/eclipse-plugin-gef-and-graph-visualization-zest